# Custom Wordpress login code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not experienced enough to edit the core file or function php file without assistance

Need code for custom WordPress login page

Comment: Why don't you test that plugin if it fit your needs?

Comment: Theme my Login / TML works quite well right out of the box. https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own login with following code:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
$creds['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
$creds['remember'] = false;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) )
{
    $result['type'] = "error";
    $result['message'] =  __('Username or password is incorrect', 'rs-theme');
}
else
{
    $result['type'] = "success";
    $result['message'] = __('Logged in successfully', 'rs-theme');;
}
```